# Getting Data from WIN32_PnPDeviceProperty using C#

Tags: c#, driver, wmi

I read data from class WIN32_PnPDeviceProperty using Powershell and command PS
C:> Get-PnpDeviceProperty -InstanceId ''.

Similarly I want to read data using C# framework, so I wrote sample code like follow

```
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM SWD\\PRINTENUM\\{E82E5EFD-6616-4E4F-9A96-7D94554A8BF0}");
        ManagementObjectSearcher deviceSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        foreach (ManagementObject device in deviceSearch.Get())
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Driver ----------------------------------------");
                foreach (var item in device.Properties)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}      :   {1}",item.Name,item.Value);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
        }
```

But Query returns empty. I am not entirely sure the way to run query or get info using above method is correct or not.

Is there any other way to read data from the mentioned class ?

Comment: Your WQL looks wrong. At the very least it needs to include WIN32_PnPDeviceProperty.

Comment: I tried using query "SELECT * FROM win32_PNPDeviceProperty" initially
But result was same